Cannot run Flutter project, Java version is null
I just changed to a new laptop and moved all my Flutter projects onto the new device. When I'm trying to run one of the projects, it says my Java version is null. How do I solve this?
My Java version is 17 and Gradle is 7.6.3:

When running flutter run, it says:

Even though the environment only shows JDK 17, I don't know why it is suggesting JDK 21 for JAVA_HOME when I haven't set it like that:

flutter doctor -v shows that the Java binary is in jdk-21 where I don't have it:

On my previous device it is running well, but why doesn't work on my new device?

update the path v eriable of Flutter sdk in system variable in Environment Variable . Restart the Android studio.

System variable looks fine to me. Have you tried updating the PATH Variable ?
Find the Path variable under System variables and click edit.
If it's fine too try re syncing your Gradle Files.
And additionally you can clean the Flutter project if needed with these-
flutter clean
flutter pub get

